# Disabled ribbon buttons in the library view

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

We had a user who installed IE 10. This messed up the users access to SharePoint 2010 sites. Then we removed IE 10, but in IE 9 the user still has a couple of Ribbon buttons that she used to use in SharePoint (with IE 9) that are now disabled. This started after going back to IE 9. The disabled buttons are the Datasheet View and Open with Explorer.

We checked to make sure that the datasheet view was enabled in the library. Then logged in as another user on the same computer and both buttons showed as enabled for the other user. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are they using the 64 bit version of IE by chance?

Comment: I asked the tech on site about that. He has not responded yet. I did see that in some of the searches I've reviewed. - Thanks

Comment: I just confirmed that the user is using the 32 bit version of Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: check the Managed Add Ons, you should see a NameCtrl by Microsoft (or similar) in there, make sure it's enabled.

Comment: Does the user have permissions to run activex controls?

Comment: The problem seems to be solved. The tech on site uninstalled IE 9, uninstalled the default browser, then installed IE 10. This seems to have solved most of the users problems (so far). We are monitoring the situation.

Comment: Remember to answer your question with the solution and mark is as answered to allow people to find answers easier in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with PirateEric... Check that they are NOT using the 64-bit version of IE, it doen't support many active x controls. I had a user lose the Open in Access button, when we tried it in the 32-bit IE it worked.

Others will say do a repair of Microsoft Office. If your disabled buttons are Office related, it may fix it too.

Comment: We ended up having to rebuild the users profile. She used the buttons that were disabled frequently. Now fixed. Lesson learned: Do not upgrade to IE 10 and unset your automatic updates.